# sum of records retrieved using group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to calculate the total no of periods conducted till date?
The following is the structure of my database..and there can be two subjects at a time for a section (electives)

```
section  period  subject     date
------------------------------------
A        1       SUB1     2020-01-07
A        2       E1       2020-01-07
A        2       E2       2020-01-07
A        3       SUB2     2020-01-07
A        4       SUB3     2020-01-07
A        5       SUB4     2020-01-07
A        1       SUB4     2020-01-08
A        2       SUB2     2020-01-08
A        3       E1       2020-01-08
A        3       E2       2020-01-08
A        4       SUB1     2020-01-08
A        5       SUB3     2020-01-08
```

And I've used the query as follows:

```
select count(distinct period) 'noofper' 
from testtable 
where section='A' 
and date<="2020-01-08" 
group date
```

And i'm getting the result as

```
noofper
--------
5
5
```

And I want the result as

```
noofper
-------
10
```

**And How can I modify the query so that I get the above result?**

Comment: Your sample data does not seem to agree with your expected output, and I don't understand your question.

Comment: `SELECT SUM([your query here]) noofper`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Group BY` and combine both `date` and `period` in your `Count`

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct CONCAT(CAST(period AS CHAR),CAST(DAYOFYEAR(date) AS CHAR))) 'noofper' 
FROM testtable 
WHERE section ='A' AND date <= "2020-01-08"
```

[**DB FIDDLE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=59d2a97f2407f20df7d8f4090da50552)

**Updated**

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct period, date) 'noofper' 
FROM testtable 
WHERE section ='A' AND date <= "2020-01-08"
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=441a3bdcf6ede3850dabd7ac27cf873b)**

Comment: You don't need to cast, you can define multiple columns in the count: `COUNT(DISTINCT period, dater)`

Comment: yes, your solution is good +1 but except for redundant casting as scragar already told.

Comment: Btw, remove `DAYOFYEAR()` function, since it fails provided dater column having same values with month and day for different year. So consider [`COUNT(DIstinct period ,dater)`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=601f2a524305ff305b185033b42beb3a)

Answer (score 0):

you can use sum without group to do it

```sql
    select count(distinct period) 'noofper' from testtable where section='A' and date<="2020-01-08"
```

if you can another logic then you use `subquery + sum` to do it

```
select sum('noofper') 'noofper' 
from (
    select count(distinct period) 'noofper' from testtable where section='A' and date<="2020-01-08" group date
    /*some logic*/
) T
```

and result :

```
noofper
-------
10
```